# Solving Nonlinear differential equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I've been trying to calculate the motion of a Frisbee accounting for drag, lift, and weight, but have reached the nonlinear differential equation system

$$
\begin{align}
x'&=\frac{-Dx^3}{m\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
y'&=\frac{Ax}{m}+\frac{Dx^2y}{m\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-g
\end{align}
$$
where $m,D,A,g$ and constants with initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $x(0)=x_0$

Any ideas on how to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ the components of velocity?

Comment: Yeah, they're the components of the Frisbee's velocity